# Run a clock or timer even when app closes - Android

Tags: java, android, service, timer, clock

Ever played Candy Crush?  Know how you run out of lives and have to wait 30 minutes to regenerate a new life and up to a maximum of 5?  That is idea I am trying to implement in my app but I am uncertain on how to have code running even when the user closes app and/or phone.

My question is how to have a timer constantly running in the background of phone until the timer hits X minutes.  Would I use the `Timer` class for this?  Because I am familiar with that class and already have a form of it implemented in my app.

Comment: short answer you need to use `Alarm manger`.

Comment: start a service and registerd alarmmanager in service and alarmreceiver to do any action after alarm get executed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two pieces to your question:

- To actually have a timer running so that you have an action taken after a certain period of time, use the `AlarmManager`. This should only be used if you are going to proactively interrupt or notify the user.
- Your scenario doesn't actually need a timer, and it's more efficient not to use one unnecessarily. Instead, store a timestamp. When your app is opened again, compare the current time to the timestamp and calculate the effect. In the regenerating-lives example, you'd compare timestamps, see that 100 minutes have passed, divide by 30 minutes, and add 3 lives (maybe keeping the extra 10 minute remainder).

Answer (score 1):

If you want timer to run in background you may use `AlarmManager`. You can set Alarm at specified intervals or you can set it in service if you want single shot alarms. Also while using AlarmManager beware that if your phone goes down then all alarms you've set will be vanished. So take care that you are saving alarm times before phone goes off. Take a look at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

While using AlarmManager, use correct `PendingIntent` flags or you could lose previous alarms. If you still want more information you can raise here or have a google.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can keep a timer running for you application even when the application is closed. Here is an idea i think about:

- You need to start a timer when the life is gone and your application is running.
- On your application close event, save that timer value in a persistent storage such as file
- On appliction start, read the timer value from the persistent storage, and restart the timer for the remaining time
- Once timer expires, generate a new life.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13629884/735142) answer that might be of great help. Hope it helps others.

> There are several different approaches.
>
> - You can make use of the System's AlarmManager.
> - You can make your own    Service.
> - You can make your TimerObject persist.

Check the link for the complete answer and links.